# Load file content inside controller in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a css file called 'style.css' and I want to load its content inside a controller. I didn't find any relevant solution when reading the official documentation (Cookbook included).

Comment: Have you tried php  'file_get_contents'  ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Symfony2 provides a component called "Finder", check the [doc](http://symfony.com/en/doc/current/components/finder.html)

Answer (score 23):

I think you would first need to get the path to the CSS directory, using something like:

```
$path = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../css' . '/path/to/file.css';
```

Then, load the CSS file into a string:

```
$css = file_get_contents($path);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

I found a simple solution if you have the path to the file then

```
$file = new SplFileInfo('/path/to/file.css', '', '');
```

and the method `getContents` does the magic

```
$file->getContents();
```

But you will have to include the class

```
use Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo;
```

is also part of the finder library, but you don't need to search for the file you want to read.

Comment: It should be the correct answer